# AngularJS not working in my SF2 app

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

i'm building a fairly simple API with **Symfony2** and now i'm trying to make some simple pages with **AngularJS** within my bundle to eventually display the results of my API calls.

***How do i make AngularJS work properly?***

I generated a bundle through `app/console bundle:generate` so i'm working under src/Portfolio/Bundle/APIBundle, and that's where i'm basically putting all my resources etc. **everything** really.

Javascripts are under `src/Portfolio/Bundle/APIBundle/Resources/public/js`

**js/KitchenSink.js**

```
angular.module('KitchenSink', [], function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol  (']]');
});
```

**js/index.ctrl.js**

```
var module = angular.module('KitchenSink')

module.controller('IndexController', function(){
    var vm = this;

    vm.Title = 'Portfolio API KitchenSink';
});
```

**base template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="PortfolioAPIBundle::KitchenSink.js"></script>
    {% block head_javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body ng-app="KitchenSink">
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index partial:**

```
{% extends 'PortfolioAPIBundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Portfolio API KitchenSink{% endblock %}
{% block head_javascripts %}<script src="PortfolioAPIBundle::index.ctrl.js"></script>{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div ng-controller="IndexController as index" class="container">
        [[ index.Title ]]
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, you should not use the basic template, the symfony should be used as a backend. So you need to create a simple html template and initialize it in your angular project and then you can send the rest api requests.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix Twig templates with Angular, because they both use similar syntax. You can for example redefine what {{ and }} mean inside templates, but I highly suggest that you create a separate project or at least another root directory for your Angular app.